# JSF - selectonemenu (nullPointer)

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

Form snippet:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="supervisor" value="#{newTopic.supervisor}">
                <s:objectConverter/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{supervisors}" var="_supervisor"
                               itemValue="#{_supervisor}"
                               itemLabel="#{_supervisor.name.firstName} #{_supervisor.name.lastName}"></f:selectItems>   
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:commandButton action="#{newTopicAction.createTopic}" value="Create topic"/>
```

Controller action:

```
@Model
public class NewTopicAction implements Serializable{
    @Inject
    private TopicManager topicManager;

    private ThesisTopic newTopic;

    public String createTopic(){
        topicManager.createTopic(newTopic);
        return "topics?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        newTopic = new ThesisTopic();
    }

    @Produces
    @Model
    public ThesisTopic getNewTopic(){
        return newTopic;
    }
}
```

Why isn't newTopic.supervisor populated with selected supervisor, when newTopicAction.createTopic is invoked?  Every other field works as expected, except this one. It may be something about selectOneMenu what i don't understand properly.

Comment: Can you exclude that your `NewTopicAction` bean is re-created during or after submit and thus resetting the `newTopic` field? Then you should switch to a broader scope than request scope.

Comment: That did help, however I don't get why. Re-creation of NewTopicAction bean isnt't cousing any problems in populating of other fields. How is selectOneMenu different in its behaviour than e.g. inputText?.